# Как сбрасывать данные каждый раз в 12 ночи?

Tags: swift, xcode

Сейчас у меня есть несколько данных, которые я хочу сбрасывать каждый раз в 12 ночи.
Я следовал идее сравнивать текущую дату с датой у пользователя. Написал следующую функцию:

```
func resetDataEveryNight() {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let str = df.string(from: Date())
    //сохраняю дату в UserDefaults
    UserSettings.userDate = str
    print(UserSettings.userDate!)
    //если дата сходится, то выходим
    if str == UserSettings.userDate {
        return
    } else {
        //если нет, то сбрасываем данные ниже
        UserSettings.userDate = str
        currentValue.text = "0"
        resultValue.text = UserSettings.result
        progressBar.progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
        addedDrinksArray.removeAll()
    }
}
```

Но данная функция у меня не работает. Данные ночью не сбрасываются. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: Вы сравниваете всегда два одинаковых значения. str и UserSettings.userDate в вашем случае всегда равны в момент сравнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я что-то не пойму

```
let str = df.string(from: Date())

UserSettings.userDate = str

if str == UserSettings.userDate
```

какие ожидания на 3 й строчке?
Думаю проблема во второй строке она не нужна или проверка перед присваиванием

Answer (score 1):

вы сначала сохраняете строку, а ниже тут же сраниваете с ней, поэтому блок `else` у вас никогда не выполняется

```
UserSettings.userDate = str
print(UserSettings.userDate!)
//если дата сходится, то выходим
if str == UserSettings.userDate {
    return
}
```

по меньшей мере вам нужно убрать `UserSettings.userDate = str` и инициализировать `UserSettings.userDate` иначе